# Saving long detail in DB or in file?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, file

Developing an `asp.net` site on `.NET Framework 4.0` and `SQL SERVER 2008`.
When my admin member saves detail about project from **[HTMLEditorExtender](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/HTMLEditorExtender/HTMLEditorExtender.aspx)** where do i save it?

- Can i save this in `Database`? (varchar has 8000 chars) Detail can be large.
- or in `File`?

What is the best practice? 

For now i saved it in `Files` because `SQL Hosting` has less DB space than `Disk space`.

If i saved it in `File` then How to get the formated data (with pictures and links) back?

Please Give me the best path to follow. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You can use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `VARCHAR(8000)` - it can hold around 2GB of data.

However, if you are saving HTML, consider using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` if the posted data may contain Unicode characters (think international audience).

Microsoft research have a good whitepaper about storing files in and out of the database which makes good reading - [To Blob or not to Blob](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=64525).

Comment: @syedmohsin - That's something you need to discuss with your host and one consideration to take when you decide what works for you.